# Spring Security: как сделать разделение ролей?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Как в Spring сделать разделение ролей? Если, например, стоит, что администратор (значение из базы) true, то открыта конкретная ссылка для просмотра в jsp и на эту страницу (на которую вела ссылка) вход закрыт прочим пользователям (с другими ролями).

Это делается через Spring Security, верно?

UPD: Буду рад любым советам. Кто-то поставил минус, просьба отписаться в комментариях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так, например

**some_page.jsp**

```
<sec:authorize url="/admin">
  <a href="/admin">Админка</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

**SomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String admin(Model model) {
        return "admin";
    }
}
```

Совет простой - попробуйте почитать [документацию](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/), там всё очень подробно описано.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде подходит!